# How to present UIImagePickerController or open the Camera in a Landscape-only app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating an application that only works in landscape mode.

During sign up I want to open the camera or present a UIImagePickerController, but the app is crashing with the following error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'`

How can I present an Image Picker or Camera in Landscape?

Answer (score 6):

```
I found solution, case closed. i add in my appdelegate.m:

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iPad */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: The solution is good but what i see is crash gone but the app display in only one fourth portion of iPad simulator after picker view get display. is this simulator issue or something missing?

Comment: it also rotate in portrait + landscape mode both ...even in only landscape supported apps.

Comment: Why does this solution work...?  The question didn't say anything about being on both iPad/iPhone

Comment: portion of iPad simulator after picker view get display please solve this issues i am stuck user1960279.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 solution that work for both iPhone and iPad

```
func openGallary(_ sender:UIButton)
    {
        imagepicker?.delegate = self
        imagepicker?.allowsEditing = false
        imagepicker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        {
            self.present(imagepicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {

            imagepicker?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            let presentationController = imagepicker?.popoverPresentationController
            // You must set a sourceView or barButtonItem so that it can
            // draw a "bubble" with an arrow pointing at the right thing.
            presentationController?.sourceView = sender
            self.present(imagepicker!, animated: true) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very underrated. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: yup.. Highly underrated answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in iOS 9, and none of the proposed solutions I found (here or on similar questions on SO) worked for me. But, I found a solution using the UIPopoverPresentationController that was introduced in iOS 8. This is what I'm doing, in an app that is portrait-only on iPhone, and landscape-only on iPad. In my app delegate, I have this:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication,
      supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?)
      -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
      return .Landscape
    } else {
      return .Portrait
    }
  }
```

Then in the view controller that needs to show the photo picker:

```
@IBAction func choosePictureFromLibrary() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    // Set the presentation style and grab the presentation controller,
    // which is created for you.
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    let presentationController = imagePickerController.popoverPresentationController

    // You must set a sourceView or barButtonItem so that it can 
    // draw a "bubble" with an arrow pointing at the right thing.
    presentationController?.sourceView = photoButton

    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true) {}
  }
```

Using the `.Popover` modal presentation style gives a nice, compact (basically iPhone-sized) view overlaying the screen on iPad. When you run on iPhone it just runs full-screen like a normal modal view.

Comment: Additionally I had to subclass UIImagePicker (when used in landscape) and override `var supportedInterfaceOrientations` to return `[.landscape, .portrait]` (iOS 10)

Answer (score -4):

Implement the `shouldAutorotate` method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return  NO;
}
```

[image: This image shows the landscape orientation checked, you need to do the same]

Add this code to `PUUIAlbumListViewController` and all other view controllers. Make sure that you checked only landscape (landscape left and landscape right) in your Target.

Comment: I have not created PUUIAlbumListViewController class.and app is still crashing.

Comment: paste the above code snippet in all view controllers, including PUUIAlbumListViewController.

Comment: I don't think many people outside of Apple have access to PUUIAlbumListViewController, @saif